# Does Android SDK have a mechanism to get the associate identifier for a play store app for monetization of its content?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

What if I don't want to have banner ads in my android application, but still want to provide links to other apps in the play store (as part of my app content). However it should act like how the same app came as a banner ad to enable monetization of my content.

Does Google Android SDK provide a way to get the registered associate/referrer ID for any app in the play store, that I can use while showing that app for download in my application? Eg. If I enable banner ads, Google owns the content of it and shows relevant ads (including ads to download and install another mobile app). Instead I want to enable download and install of other mobile apps in my android application, but at the same time earn money for those app downloads/installs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show ads for your other apps in short, Cross Promote apps, that feature is available in AdMob. Here you won't be paid for showing your ad. because your other app is getting promoted for free.

The other thing you are saying is that you want some app ads to be shown in your app. Well, firstly they should be paying or else how will you earn money. So you got to agree with them.

But there is DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) for similar purpose AFAIK. You can see which ads to show or not. Only if the advertisers is available in that list from which you can select ads to show.